# Custom CType vs. CType list & list_type

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, fluid-styled-content

In my custom TYPO3 Extbase extension, I created a backend module to manage person records. Now I need a content element to show the records in the frontend.

I see two ways to achieve this:

- Use the CType "list" and a custom list_type. Provide a FlexForm for additional fields
- Use a custom CType, a FSC DataProcessor and TCA for additional fields

What's the best, most future-proof way to achieve this in TYPO3 CMS 7.6? What's the (dis-)advantage from one over the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The short answer**

It doesn't matter, both ways are valid and will be supported in the future as well.

**The long answer**

I would always differ between a content element and a plugin but I agree that sometimes the difference might be hard to get.

A *content element* holds all information it should show inside its own record. As an example you could take an image gallery where all images are saved in a relation with FAL. Processors can be used to add additional information like done with FAL records.

A *plugin* contains controllers and actions and shows data which are saved somewhere else, e.g. records or from an XML or any other source.

---

Both types could be enhanced by providing a configuration using flexforms or additional fields.